# What Cocoa/Core Foundation helper functions do you wish you knew about 2 years ago?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I just discovered the NSRect helper functions in NSGeometry.h (i.e. NSMidX, NSMaxX, etc...)

These would have made some repetitive coding much easier.  I knew about NSMakeRect, NSMouseInRect, NSOffsetRect and many others but somehow missed the functions that aid in recalculating NSRect geometry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found NSStringFrom*() helpful when logging structs like CGRect, CGPoint, etc.

You can find a comprehensive overview at Apple's [Foundation Functions Reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20170506162910/https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/foundation_functions) (Wayback Machine link).

Comment: Oh man... I had recreated several of those. Good answer to a good question!

Answer (score 5):

Helper function to draw three part images with left cap, fill and right cap. Ideal for custom buttons

```
void NSDrawThreePartImage(NSRect frame,
    NSImage *startCap,
    NSImage *centerFill,
    NSImage *endCap,
    BOOL vertical,
    NSCompositingOperation op,
    CGFloat alphaFraction,
    BOOL flipped
);
```

Also look for **NSDrawNinePartImage**

Answer (score 4):

This is one that I wish I had known about 6 months ago.  I was creating our first iPhone application and I wanted to create a simple help file that was based on HTML using the UIWebView Controller.

However I could not figure out how to embed local images that I had stored in the Bundle and I did not want the user to have to have internet access to fetch the images from a server.

Little did I know I could do the following to get images from the Main Bundle

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *bundleBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: bundlePath];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL: bundleBaseURL];
```

The Image in your HTML can then call local images directly.

```
<img src="yourImageFromTheMainBundle.jpg" />
```

I had no idea I could set the baseURL with the location of the Bundle.

Answer (score 4):

Much of the stuff in NSPathUtilities.h. I did know about it two years ago, but when I first found it I wished I’d seen it two years earlier. :-)

At some point I wasted quite a bit of time because I didn’t know about [NSCountedSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscountedset?language=objc), and made a mess of my dictionary-based replacement. I know of several cases where people have done the same sort of thing because they didn’t know about [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsset?language=objc) at all. Another good “hidden” collection is [CFBinaryHeap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfbinaryheap?language=objc), which implements a priority queue, but doesn’t have an NS equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

One I remember

```
+ (NSBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(NSRect)rect xRadius:(CGFloat)xRadius yRadius:(CGFloat)yRadius
```

Granted figuring out how to draw a rounded rectangle manually is a pretty good exercise. There are others that I am just so used to now.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a colour from a pattern image with

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mypattern.png"]];
```

Comment: This would be a neat trick because the public iPhone SDK isn't even a year old yet.  However the Cocoa equivalent with NSColor & NSImage has always been there.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is a shortcut instead of a library call that I missed, but it is in the spirit of the thread.

One shortcut that I use alot is using an inline format statement in NSLog calls.

```
NSLog(@"x=%@", [someobject className]);
```

instead of the more verbose

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"x=%@", [someobject classname]]);
```

Comment: That's not a shortcut; that's the only correct way to do it. If the result of stringWithFormat: (or whatever string you pass to NSLog) ends up containing, say, “%@”, then NSLog will try to insert an object there—but you didn't pass one. So it takes a garbage pointer, sends it a message, and boom.

Comment: Doesn't deserve a minus though. :-)